# On the implementation of a python program with classes

Tags: python, class

I'm new to this website and to programming in general so please don't be too harsh on this newby-ish question.

As the title of this question says, I am trying to write a program in Python that incorporates classes. It is a program that should find words in a given story. This story has a title, a GUID, a subject, a summary and a link. In this case, I would like the program to find words in the title of the story. The subclass I made that should do the trick doesn't work properly, though. Here is what I tried thus far:

```
class NewsStory(object):
    def __init__(self,guid,title,subject,summary,link):
        self.guid = guid
        self.title = title
        self.subject = subject        
        self.summary = summary
        self.link = link
    def get_guid(self):
        return self.guid
    def get_title(self):
        return self.title
    def get_subject(self):
        return self.subject
    def get_summary(self):
        return self.summary
    def get_link(self):
        return self.link

class Trigger(object):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        """
        Returns True if an alert should be generated
        for the given news item, or False otherwise.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError

class WordTrigger(object):
    def __init__(self,word):
        self.word = word
    def is_word_in(self,text): 
        #check if self.word is in text

        texter = text.lower()


        for char in texter:
            if char in str.punctuation : 
                char = ' '

        #text_List.append(char)
        text_List = text.split(' ')

        for string in text_List: 
            if self.word == string: 
                return True     
        return False

class TitleTrigger(WordTrigger):

    def evaluate(self,story):
        print "story:", story.title
        return self.is_word_in(story.title)
```

Yet when I test the program, I get the following Failure: "title trigger failed to fire when the word appeared in the title."

**Question 1**: What did I do wrong?

Furthermore, I am having trouble understanding classes in general.

**Question 2**: Could you please suggest an accessible reference to an introduction to classes in Python? I tried the some sources like the Python Documentation, wikibooks and tutorials point, but I did not become much wiser from those sources. Do you have something "better"? This could be anything: a book, a website, an article, et cetera.

Comment: For a quick resource about classes, take a browse through here: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex40.html

Comment: How exactly are you running your code? I see a bunch of classes, but nothing to set them up/load in data/call them.

Comment: The error message isn't generated by any of the code you posted, so it's difficult to say what the error means. How are you testing the code? There seems to be a script that uses the classes you define.

Comment: Also, a bit of a style tip: you don't really need to write getter and setter methods such as `obj.get_link()`, `obj.get_guid()`, etc. You can just directly manipulate the attributes by doing `obj.link` and `obj.guid`. (In other languages, that's not necessarily the case, but explicit getter and setter methods are kinda unnecessary in Python)

Answer (score 0):

First at all, some tips about Python and Object Oriented Programming:

1. Is better to treat the attributes as public instead of using getters and setters. If you want to change the implementation of the class, you could try using [properties](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#property).
2. If you want have variables that you won't use outside the class, use the underscore at the variable name: `self._word = word`.
3. Try to leave empty lines between methods.

I recommend you to read the [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

I see you are using str.punctuation, but the str type hasn't that attribute. I think you wanted to use the `string` module:

```
import string
if char in string.punctuation:
    # do stuff
```

But then, I see you are not using that part of the code, and you are iterating the split text list. I would do something like this:

```
def is_word_in(self, text):
    _text = text.lower()
    return self.word in _text.split(' ')
```

By the way, I didn't get that error you said before.

Comment: I have to disagree with your advice regarding private attributes. Python never enforces any form of access control, and so good style is to always treat your instance variables as public, and _never_ to write getters and setters (since there's no way to force your clients to use them anyway). If there comes a time when you need to change the implementation of a class on the surface of your package, you can continue to support the old API using [properties](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#property).